# Using JavaScript to find the limit of a function as a variable tends to Zero?

Tags: javascript, math

Is there a JavaScript function which returns the limit of a function, say f(x), as X tends to 0? Does something like "Math.lim(f(x), 0)" exist?

Comment: Nope, gotta do that yourself or use a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality provided in core JavaScript. What you want is either to relegate that functionality to the server-side(that is of course if you have one), or to try using a JavaScript CAS.

The problem with the latter options is that there really aren't any good ones written in JavaScript in terms of functionality and completeness. 
You can take a look at [coffeequate](http://coffeequate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [this project](https://github.com/aantthony/javascript-cas), but neither one of them seem to support taking limits.

Personally, I would look into using a server-side component for such calculations. If you know Python, I would recommend [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html). Getting a simple server up to send/receive requests using Python's http.server module is straight forward, but that's outside the scope of this question.

For reference, this is what functionality the [Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) provides.